# How to glReadPixels properly to write the data into QImage in Linux

Tags: qt, opengl, glfw, glew, glreadpixels

## Summary

I want to write the opengl pixels(GL_RGB) by glReadPixels to a QImage.This renders correct, but when i resize the window, it scales weird and distorts my shape(triangle).

## What i tried

I tried `(QImage)img.scale(width(),height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio)`
but it didn't solve the problem.

Played with how i write the pixels buffer from `glReadPixels` to `QImage` but No.Didn't work.

Should i read the pixels in three buffers(GLubyte *rpixel,*gpixel,*bpixel) or on one(GLubyte **pixels)?Which one is the easiest because i will resize the array when i will resize my window(so i want dynamic arrays).

## Some code

I have uploaded a minimal code recreating the bug-weird behaviour in github.Download and compile using the Qt Creator.
https://github.com/rivenblades/GlReadPixelsQT/tree/master

## Pictures

Here is how i wanted(it works when not resizing)
[image]

Here is after resizing(Weird behaviour)
[image]

As you can see, when resizing, the image gets splitted at right and contunues at left at probably another row.So i am guessing the size of the image is wrong(needs more width?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the start of each row of an image is assumed to be aligned to 4 bytes. This is because the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` respectively `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` parameter is by default 4, see [`glPixelStore`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml).
When a framebuffer is read by [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` parameter is considered.

If you want to read the image in a tightly packed memory, with not alignment at the start of each line, then you've to change the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` parameter to 1, before reading the color plane of the framebuffer:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glReadPixels(0,0,unchangable_w, unchangable_h, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tga.rpic);
glReadPixels(0,0,unchangable_w, unchangable_h, GL_GREEN, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tga.gpic);
glReadPixels(0,0,unchangable_w, unchangable_h, GL_BLUE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tga.bpic);
```

If that is missed, this cause a shift effect at each line of the image, except if the length of a line of the image in bytes is divisible by 4.

Comment: I added glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1); and it works correctly when i resize.However, if i resize too much, it cuts the triangle, horizontally if i resize that way, and vertically if the other way.Please, check my code on github to see the problem. [link] (https://github.com/rivenblades/GlReadPixelsQT/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Well i figured it out.I needed to call glfwSetWindowSize(GLFWwindow*,m_width,m_height); in the resizeEvent of Qt.Also i needed to pass the GLFWwindow* instance in the widget to do the previous thing.